# How to define Javascript global function accessible to JMeter WebDriver sampler

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) to test the web application's client-side performance in JMeter.

**NOTE**: Javascript is used as Groovy was not working. I need to switch to Groovy.

Everything works fine, and page load time is displayed in listeners.

A few common functions are used across the [WebDriver Samplers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/).

Is there a way to define the Javascript functions globally and use them within each [WebDriver Samplers](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)?

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var time = JavaImporter(java.time)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui);
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, time.Duration.ofSeconds(10));


WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
    WDS.log.info("Start navigating to new bus incident creation page");
    waitAndClick(pkg.By.cssSelector("#New"));
    waitAndClick(pkg.By.cssSelector("#Bus_3"));
    waitAndClick(pkg.By.cssSelector("#Bus_3_0"));
    waitUntilLoadingIsCompleted();
    WDS.log.info("Accessed the new bus incident creation page");
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();



function waitUntilLoadingIsCompleted() {
    wait.until(support_ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.cssSelector(".k-loading-text")));
    wait.until(support_ui.ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.cssSelector(".k-loading-text")));
}


function waitAndClick(element){
    wait.until(support_ui.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    WDS.browser.findElement(element).click()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of storing your functions into a separate .js file and reading them using [`load()` function](https://anuradha-15.medium.com/loading-scripts-using-nashorn-85585f495cf0), this way you will be able to refer the "common" functions without having to copy and paste them again and again.

Going forward I would like to remind that [Nashorn scripting engine has been removed in OpenJDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372) so you won't be able to use `javascript` engine with newer JVMs so it worth migrating to Groovy as soon as possible, moreover it's [recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [it has much better performance comparing to other engines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter).

Comment: There was an issue in using Groovy with the WebDriver Sample. Hence using Javascript as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is really the wrong model to test client performance.   Use the builkt in tools of your browser, along with the JavaScript profiling tools.  If you want larger sample sets, then include a RUM agent in your code and collect all of the w3c Navtiming metrics in your choice of tool (Splunk, Datadog, Dynatrace, Elasticstack,....) for statistical analysis

Comment: I am using single user with the `WebDriver Sampler` while `HTTP Request Sampler` is user for loading the server. Let me check the other options too.

Comment: Use a single user with Google DevTools.  Run it against GTMetrix.  Your HTTP request sampler tells you nothing about the performance of your javascript client code on the front end.   For that matter, if you are only interested in request performance for a single user, then add the w3c time-taken metric to your web logs, walk the site manually, then dump the web request and error logs for your IP address.  Presto!  You have timings for every single request.

Comment: DevTools is useful. BTW I am using   `WebDriver Sampler` NOT `HTTP Request Sampler`.  Let me give it a try with GTMetrix. Looks like a promising tool.